# Can I generate pdf reports using Fpdf, php and data from a csv file

Tags: php, csv, fpdf

I have been trying to generate reports using Fpdf, php and mysql. There are many example on internet for that. 
Now I want to generate pdf reports using Fpdf and php, but my data is in excel file, csv. Any clue how to generate report using csv file data, or if someone can guide me any tutorial for that, i will really appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Comment: You would need to extract your data from your existing CSV first.

Comment: extract as in? another format or read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already done it using `Fpdf`, `php` and `mysql`, I think the only issue for you would be getting data from the excel sheet. `PHP` has a built in function called `fgetcsv()` that can retrieve data from an excel file. Here's a quick example.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("subjects.csv","r");

while(! feof($file)){
  // do what you want with the data here
  // either save to an array or print all to your file
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

The while loop will go row by row and save/print everthing present in that row in array format
Hope this helped. If you want to know more, I suggest you go through the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for the function.

Comment: thank you wishan. i will check this. seems a good option though.

Comment: no worries. If you have any issues with it, you can update me here and I can help you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
**First**: You should read file csv and
**Second**: then the fields use in report pdf

-------------------------------
CONTENT in FILE CSV called: contacts.csv:

Kai Jim, Refsnes, Stavanger, Norway
Hege, Refsnes, Stavanger, Norway 

-------------------------------
IN PHP:
<?php
//------------------------------------
//PRINT IN BROWSER
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

echo "PRINT DIRECT IN BROWSER<br>";
while(! feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  echo "<br/>";    
  }

fclose($file);

// ------------------------------------ 
// READ FILE AND THEN LOAD IN ARRAY
$file2 = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

$all_data="";

echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "READ FILE AND CREATE JSON STRING, THEN LOAD IN ARRAY<br>";
while(! feof($file2))
  {
    $arrData=fgetcsv($file2);

    echo $arrData[0]."<br>";
    echo $arrData[1]."<br>";
    echo $arrData[2]."<br>";
    echo $arrData[3]."<br><br`>";

  }

fclose($file2);

// THEN OPERATIONS FOR PDF GENERATING ...
?>
```